# use beautiful soup to parse a href from given html structure

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have the following given html structure

```
<li class="g">
 <div class="vsc">    
  <div class="alpha"></div>
  <div class="beta"></div>
  <h3 class="r">
   <a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com"></a>
  </h3>
 </div>
</li>
```

The above html structure keeps repeating, what can be the easiest way to parse all the links(stackoverflow.com) from the above html structure using **BeautifulSoup** and **Python**?

Comment: Is the first *div* intentionally left open - in other words, do you specifically want to parse broken HTML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[BeautifulSoup 4](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) offers a convenient way of accomplishing this, using CSS selectors:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
print [a["href"] for a in soup.select('h3.r a')]
```

This also has the advantage of constraining the selection by context: it selects only those anchor nodes that are children of a h3 node with class r.

Omitting the constraint or choosing one most suitable for the need is easy by just tweaking the selector; see the [CSS selector docs](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) for that.

Comment: Actually I want to iterate over all the elements, meaning I want to find `a href` inside `h3 class = r`, which is inside `div class vsc` which is inside `li class g`

Comment: Right. So you'd simply change the selector to 'li.g div.vsc h3.r a' which does that. Does that work for you?

Answer (score 1):

Using CSS selectors as proposed by Petri is probably the best way to do it using BS. However, i can't hold myself back to recommend using `lxml.html` and `xpath`, that are pretty much perfect for the job.

Test `html`:

```
html="""
<html>
<li class="g">
<div class="vsc"></div>    
<div class="alpha"></div>
<div class="beta"></div>
<h3 class="r">
<a href="http://www.correct.com"></a>
</h3>
</li>
<li class="g">
<div class="vsc"></div>    
<div class="alpha"></div>
<div class="beta"></div>
<h3 class="r">
<a href="http://www.correct.com"></a>
</h3>
</li>
<li class="g">
<div class="vsc"></div>    
<div class="gamma"></div>
<div class="beta"></div>
<h3 class="r">
<a href="http://www.incorrect.com"></a>
</h3>
</li>
</html>"""
```

and it's basically a oneliner:

```
    import lxml.html as lh
    doc=lh.fromstring(html)
    doc.xpath('.//li[@class="g"][div/@class = "vsc"][div/@class = "alpha"][div/@class = "beta"][h3/@class = "r"]/h3/a/@href')

    Out[264]:
    ['http://www.correct.com', 'http://www.correct.com']
```

Comment: Actually I want to iterate over all the elements, meaning I want to find `a href` inside `h3 class = r`, which is inside `div class vsc` which is inside `li class g`